# jQuery does not differentiate between span and label

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is interesting.

HTML:

```
<label name="foo"></label>
<span name="foo"></span>
```

Javascript:

```
var foo = $('[name="foo"]');
if (foo.is("span")) {
    foo.html('haha');
}
```

Both the `label` and `span` will have the same HTML text. However, if you delete the `<span>`, than the label will not have its HTML altered. Any reason why, and any way to properly differentiate between them? This is also true if you change `if(foo.is("span"))` to `if(foo.is("label"))`

Comment: Because `foo.is("span")` returns true  [Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use

```
var foo = $('[name="foo"]');
```

a **collection of elements** matching the selector will be returned. To select individual element form it, iterate over it. Using `is` on a jQuery object will return `true` if any element in matched set satisfies the condition.

[.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

> Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.

Use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$('[name="foo"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is("span")) {
        $(this).html('haha');
    }
});
```

The above code is just for the Demo purpose, the following code is equivalent of the above.

```
$('span[name="foo"]').html('haha');
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree with **Tushar**, just use

```
$('span[name="foo"]')
```

instead of

```
$('[name="foo"]')
```